# php splitting large numbers (like explode)

Tags: php, explode

i need the functionality of php explode(), but without the separators.

for example, turning the variable "12345" into an array, holding each number seperately.

is this possible? i've already googled but only found explode(), which doesn't seem to work.

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with any string in php:

```
$foo="12345";
echo $foo[0];//1
echo $foo[1];//2
//etc
```

or (from the preg_split()) page in the manual

```
$str = 'string';
$chars = preg_split('//', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($chars);
```

EVEN BETTER:

```
$str = 'string';
$chars=str_split($str, 1)
print_r($chars);
```

benchmark of preg_split() vs str_split()

```
 function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}


$str = '12345';
$time_start = microtime_float();
for ($i = 0; $i <100000; $i++) {
$chars = preg_split('//', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
//$chars=str_split($str, 1);
}
$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "$time seconds\n";
```

results:

```
str_split  =0.69
preg_split =0.9
```

Comment: `preg_split` would be a very bad choice for this

Comment: @Phil Brown why? speed? unless you happen to be doing it 10000 times will it be noticeable at a human level?

Comment: Indeed, why would you use regex for this?

Comment: my example was from the manual, but I do agree, benchmarked: 1 million times preg_split =0.9 seconds str_split=0.69 seconds, not a big issue at a human level

Comment: Firstly, if you want to use give benchmark numbers, you need to share the test. Arbitrarily giving results means absolutely nothing to me, nor should it anyone, unless we can reproduce the results. As for the differences, yes, they are going to be small. But why would you use regex for this? There is no pattern. There are functions designed to split strings, so for someone to recommend using the regex engine for this, and even defending it, seems like poor advise. That's like saying to get "hello world" printed on the screen, you should use the Zend Framework.

Answer (score 4):

If you actually want to create an array, then use str_split(), i.e.,

```
echo '<pre>'. print_r(str_split("123456", 1), true) .'</pre>';
```

would result in

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your number can be turned into string and then acted like an array

```
$i = 2342355; $i=(string)$i;
//or
$i='234523452435234523452452452';

//then

$i[2]==4

//numeration started from 0
```